# Why is the following problem impossible to solve?

Tags: puzzle, chessboard

Consider a chessboard ( an $8\times8$ board with 64 squares) and two opposite corner squares are removed.

> Why can't you cover the rest of the board with domino tiles of 2 $\times$1?
>
> What's the proof behind it?

I've read the solution on Gomory's theorem when the 2 opposite colors are removed from the chessboard. But I'm still curious behind the reason why this isn't possible.

Comment: Try covering a $4 \times 4$ board to find the reason.

Comment: Every tile covers one white square and one black square.  Your board has 32 black squares and 30 white squares.

Comment: But is that the only reason why it's not solvable.

Comment: @AnonymousI I am sure there are other proofs that show it is not solvable ... but this one is super straightforward!

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that that's the reason but what is the proof?

Comment: @AnonymousI that is the proof. It's a proof by contradiction. We could make it a little more formal, but it's still the outline of the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you place a domino, two tiles of different color are covered: one white and one black. If you remove two white squares, then you're left with 30 white squares and 32 black squares, which means one domino would have to cover 2 black squares. We know this is impossible!